# Bootstrap code structure

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form in bootstrap, I've got some questions about the work am doing.

1.Where do we place the form element inside our html? Does it have to be at the beginning of the form?

2.I have a table with repeated rows, is it recommended to do it with div or just use table for it?

3.Do I have to place div.row then div.form-group inside each other? Is this the best practice or I can just use form-group directly without a div.row as parent?

4.How can I control the size of td inside table if there's no way to do it as div? I used a table in my form and I need the td contains datepicker to be smaller than the td containing comments.

Let me know if there's something unclear. Thanks all

Comment: Comments removed as they weren't helping. Please refrain from continuing in the same vein.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF  :) appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an example to have two columns in sm. The other sizes (xs, md, lg) are not included. That means, you have the whole width of the screen in xs, md, lg. (Equal to e.g. in lg col-lg-12). The width, you change with col-xs-... col-sm-... col-md-... col-lg-...

[Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

There is no need to use a `<table>` for this. Use always `<div class="row">` as parent. Than the col class to change the width.The class row makes a margin-left and margin-right 15px:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-... col-md-...">
    Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) But what if I have a repeating table, for example, a table to enter the past experiences at work, if I use div.row and then you change the browser's size to a smaller size, it will ruin the design, maybe that's where we need to use tables to show the horizontal inline scroll when on smaller browsers or mobiles? I don't know actually. In the example you posted, you used one row, and added everything to it, I have multiple rows for each horizontal row that's going to appear in the browser, is this right? thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question with some relevant HTML to see what you actually mean. Thanks!